# Visual Studio 2015 - rebuild project after custom files (html, css) changed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build, compilation

I have C++ code with Qt. Then I have external *.html, *.css and *.js files.
Those files get compiled to the program's resources.

So what I want is that if I change content of those files (html...) that the project gets rebuild (in order to put those files into exe).

How can I do so? 
Right now VS rebuild only when *.cpp or *.h files changed. And I've added html files to project but it doesn't help.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you added the files into your resource file (resource.rc)?

Comment: @ZDF I don't have *.rc. I have *.qrc as I use Qt. And those files are of course in the *.qrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

To make change in custom files invoke compilation you have to:

1. Right-click on the file in "Solution Explorer"
2. Choose "Properties"
3. Change "Item type" from "Does not participate in build" to something else (for example "Text")

After this, if you change this file then the build process will be executed.